# how to take an arraylist of string type from one method to another method

Tags: methods, arraylist

I am a couple of semesters into learning java and I am looking to move an arraylist from one method to another.  I have look everywhere but could not find exactly what I need.
Thank you.

```
public static void addEmployee(ArrayList<String> list)
{
    int i;                  //declares i as integer

    //increments i for the array
    for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        list.get(i);        //adds employees to an arraylist

    for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        addEmployee(list.get(i)); //This does not work

}//end public static void addEmplyoee(Arraylist<String> list)

public static void searchId(ArrayList<String> list)
{

}
```

Comment: which function are you trying to add the list into in this example? is it searchId()? Your code is a little confusing why are you using 2 for loops when the top loop literally does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ArrayList as a reference:

```
searchId(list);
```

That is, *don't* pass just a *single* element using [`ArrayList.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29).